# checkbox + Model + Controller. Como pegar as linhas selecionadas?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

estou enviado a minha *model* tipada para uma *view* e carregado os dados em uma tabela onde incluo um `checkbox` para cada linha. O usuário irá selecionar os itens que interessa para posteriormente ser gravada no banco de dados. Minha dúvida está justamente neste ponto. Como faço para enviar para o *controller* os itens. Alem da minha lista de dados também envio outras informações.

Minha *model* é essa:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string CodigoUsuario { get; set; }
public string NomeUsuario { get; set; }
public List<Fornecedor> ListaFornecedorViewModels { get; set; }
```

Meu *controller* é esse:

```
public ActionResult UsuarioNovo() {
    UsuarioViewModel usuarioViewModel = new UsuarioViewModel();
    ViewData["Colaborador"] = _userLogado;
    return View(usuarioViewModel);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UsuarioNovo(UsuarioViewModel usuarioViewModel)
{
    if (usuarioViewModel.ListaFornecedorViewModels != null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(usuarioViewModel.FornecedorBusca)) {
            int iCnpj;
            var listFornecedor = new BuscaDadosFornecedorBo().BuscaRequisicaoFornecedorBo(usuarioViewModel.FornecedorBusca, "");
            usuarioViewModel.ListaFornecedorViewModels = listFornecedor;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Gravar Dados
    }
    return View(usuarioViewModel);
}
```

E essa é a minha View:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm()) {
<div class="linha">
    <div class="campo item small">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NomeUsuario)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NomeUsuario)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="linha">
    <div class="campo item small">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SobrenomeUsuario)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SobrenomeUsuario)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-content">
    <div class="linha">
        <div class="campo item">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FornecedorBusca)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FornecedorBusca)
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Buscar" />
    </div>
</div>  

@if (Model.ListaFornecedorViewModels != null) {
    <div class="table-custom">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=" " style="width: 10px;"> </th>
                    <th>Selecionar</th>
                    <th>CNPJ</th>
                    <th>RazaoSocial</th>
                    <th>Municipio</th>                                    
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                @foreach (var forn in Model.ListaFornecedorViewModels) {
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" value="@forn.Codigocnpj" name="chkForn"/></td>
                        <td>@forn.Codigocnpj</td>
                        <td>@forn.RazaoSocial</td>
                        <td>@forn.Municipio</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

}

Vou precisar dar dois `post` na mesmo action "UsuarioNovo"... O primeiro pra buscar a lista de fornecedores e o segundo para enviar os dados mais os itens da lista selecionados. Como farei isso?

---

**EDIT**

Fiz os ajustes que o @Cigano mencionou na model e estou utilizando **BeginCollectionItem**, porém o selecionado está vindo sempre como false e os demais campos como null. Veja as imagens:

[image: Grid]

E no meu código mostra isso:
[image: codigo]

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Já instalou o [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/)?

Comment: E o que isso poderia me ajudar Cigano?

Comment: A resolver seu problema. Se não, coloco uma resposta.

Comment: Não sei como utilizar o que mencionou. Por favor, aguardo a sua resposta.

Comment: Se você quer que os campos vão para o Controller, é preciso transformá-los em `@Html.EditorFor()` ou `@Html.HiddenFor()`, mas só recomendo fazer isso para o Id do Fornecedor. Não para todos os campos.

Comment: Boa... Vou fazer o hiddenfor() para pegar o ID. Porem minha duvida esta ainda quando envio os dados para o controller e o check estão todos nulos.

Comment: Deu certo agora?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é uma boa prática deixar na mesma *Action* funções muito diferentes, como montar uma *ViewModel* e persistir um usuário novo. O correto seria você fazer o seguinte:

```
public ActionResult UsuarioNovo() 
{
    UsuarioViewModel usuarioViewModel = new UsuarioViewModel {
        ListaFornecedorViewModels = new BuscaDadosFornecedorBo().BuscaRequisicaoFornecedorBo(usuarioViewModel.FornecedorBusca, "")
    };
    ViewData["Colaborador"] = _userLogado;
    return View(usuarioViewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UsuarioNovo(UsuarioViewModel usuarioViewModel)
{
    if (usuarioViewModel.ListaFornecedorViewModels != null)
    {
        //Gravar Dados
    }

    return View(usuarioViewModel);
}
```

Como mencionei em comentário, isto é um caso clássico do uso do pacote [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/). [Há várias perguntas e respostas a respeito que você pode se basear](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=begincollectionitem), mas vou deixar o caminho pavimentado para a solução.

Se o objetivo é trabalhar com uma lista de fornecedores com uma `CheckBox`, nada mais justo que definir a `CheckBox` no *ViewModel*, afinal, você não vai salvar o fornecedor. Apenas pegar se ele foi selecionado ou não.

```
public class FornecedorViewModel
{
    public bool Selecionado { get; set; }
    public Fornecedor Fornecedor { get; set; }
}
```

Mudando o *ViewModel* de Usuário:

```
public class UsuarioViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CodigoUsuario { get; set; }
    public string NomeUsuario { get; set; }
    public List<FornecedorViewModel> Fornecedores { get; set; }
}
```

Vamos ter que mudar um pouco nosso método `GET`:

```
public ActionResult UsuarioNovo() 
{
    UsuarioViewModel usuarioViewModel = new UsuarioViewModel {
        Fornecedores = new BuscaDadosFornecedorBo()
                           .BuscaRequisicaoFornecedorBo(usuarioViewModel.FornecedorBusca, "")
                           .Select(f => new FornecedorViewModel { Fornecedor = f })
                           .ToList()
    };

    ViewData["Colaborador"] = _userLogado;
    return View(usuarioViewModel);
}
```

Sua *View*, portanto, fica assim:

```
@if (Model.Fornecedores != null) {
    <div class="table-custom">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=" " style="width: 10px;"> </th>
                    <th>Selecionar</th>
                    <th>CNPJ</th>
                    <th>RazaoSocial</th>
                    <th>Municipio</th>                                    
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                @foreach (var form in Model.Fornecedores) {
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(_ => form.Selecionado)
                        <td>@form.Fornecedor.Codigocnpj</td>
                        <td>@form.Fornecedor.RazaoSocial</td>
                        <td>@form.Fornecedor.Municipio</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

Agora vamos usar o `BeginCollectionItem`.

```
@if (Model.Fornecedores != null) {
    <div class="table-custom">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=" " style="width: 10px;"> </th>
                    <th>Selecionar</th>
                    <th>CNPJ</th>
                    <th>RazaoSocial</th>
                    <th>Municipio</th>                                    
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                @foreach (var form in Model.Fornecedores) {
                    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Fornecedores"))
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(_ => form.Selecionado)
                            <td>@form.Fornecedor.Codigocnpj</td>
                            <td>@form.Fornecedor.RazaoSocial</td>
                            <td>@form.Fornecedor.Municipio</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

Com isso, fica bem fácil de terminar a lógica:

```
if (usuarioViewModel.Fornecedores != null)
{
    foreach (usuarioViewModel.Fornecedores.Where(f => f.Selecionado))
    {
        // Gravar dados
    }
}
```

Comment: Fiz um outro comentário abaixo. O que fiz de errado?

Comment: Amigo, isto não é um fórum. Você não fez um comentário, mas sim, tentou responder à pergunta. Use o botão de edição da sua pergunta para editar. Já fiz isso por você agora, mas nas próximas edite sua pergunta. Não coloque uma resposta.

Comment: Entendi... É que queria enviar a imagem para demostrar o erro e não consegui por aqui.